# How old was Hercule Poirot?

Tags: agatha-christie, hercule-poirot

The New York Times record Hercule Poirot's age as "unknown" in their obituary:

> Hercule Poirot, a Belgian detective who became internationally famous, has died in England. His age was unknown.
>
> Source: Lask, Thomas. "[Hercule Poirot Is Dead; Famed Belgian Detective"](https://www.nytimes.com/1975/08/06/archives/hercule-poirot-is-dead-famed-belgian-detective-hercule-poirot-the.html), New York Times, 6 August 1975.

If I'm not mistaken, all we know for certain is that Poirot is retired when he first appears, something Agatha Christie expressed regret for:

> What a mistake I made there. The result is that my fictional detective must be well over a hundred by now.
>
> Source: *Agatha Christie: An Autobiography*, Agatha Christie

Do we have a more specific figure for Poirot's age?

Comment: Some useful info here;  http://www.poirot.us/age.php

Comment: @Valorum You could turn that into a decent answer ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor - And while that's true, I don't really subscribe to the idea that he's aging in realtime (albeit with a slowtime ratio) which largely invalidates the conclusion.

Comment: @Valorum: there's a problem with Poirot's age even if he doesn't age in real time.  The first Poirot story *The Mysterious Affair at Styles* makes it clear that Hastings meets Poirot the first time in that novel, and says that Poirot was already a policeman in 1904.  But Hastings and Poirot meet many times in later stories, and the stories often reference earlier stories, and sometimes to real world events such as the world wars.  It seems clear enough that a lot of time has to pass between the storie, even if it's not 52 years.

Comment: @b_jonas - Perhaps each book exists within its own self-contained universe.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the Wikipedia page on Hercule Poirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot#Death) and based on quotations from [*Curtain*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtain_(novel)), Poirot died in October 1949, thirty-three years after he [first met](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Affair_at_Styles) Captain Hastings in June 1916. (He *wasn't* actually retired by that point, but he was a refugee escaping from World War I: it's unclear [when exactly he retired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot#Retirement)). We know that he was a detective with the Brussels police force by 1893, when he tried to solve the case of [*The Chocolate Box*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poirot%27s_Early_Cases#The_Chocolate_Box). If we assume that he was 20-40 years old in 1893, he would have been born between 1853 and 1873, fled as a refuge to Britain at the age of 43 to 63, and would have died somewhere around the age of 76 to 96, which makes sense to me. If he was 55 when he moved to Britain -- at or around retirement age -- that gives us a birth year of 1861 and a death age of 88.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It is not possible to put together a consistent biography of Poirot that includes all the stories.

#### Chronology

Precise dates are very rare in the Poirot corpus, and there are few references to historical events that can be used to give a *terminus post quem*, but here is a selection of significant dates.

- > “I had a bad failure in Belgium in **1893**. You recollect, Hastings? I recounted it to you. The affair of the box of chocolates.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1932). *Peril at End House*, chapter 15. London: Collins.</sub>

  In the story itself Poirot says, “At that time, *mon ami*, I was, as you know, a member of the Belgian detective force” but as to the date he is vague:

  > “It was at the time of the terrible struggle in France between church and state.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1923). ‘The Clue of the Chocolate Box’. *The Sketch*, issue 1582. Reprinted in *Poirot’s Early Cases*.</sub>

  This places the story during the conflict over state secularism that occupied the last quarter of the 19th century and culminated in the [*Loi du 9 décembre 1905*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1905_French_law_on_the_Separation_of_the_Churches_and_the_State).

  However, in *Cards on the Table* Poirot says that his last failure was “twenty-eight years ago”:

  > “Don't you ever have a failure, Monsieur Poirot?"
  >
  > “The last time was twenty-eight years ago,” said Poirot with dignity. “And even then, there were circumstances—but no matter.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1936). *Cards on the Table*, chapter 15. London: Collins.</sub>

  When does *Cards on the Table* take place? It must post-date *The A.B.C. Murders*, since Miss Meredith says:

  > “I know all about you, Monsieur Poirot. It was you who really solved the A.B.C. crimes.”
  >
  > <sub>*Cards on the Table*, chapter 2.</sub>

  And *The A.B.C. Murders* is set in 1935:

  > It was in **June of 1935** that I came home from my ranch in South America for a stay of about six months.
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1936). *The ABC Murders*, chapter 1. London: Collins.</sub>

  So Poirot’s “twenty-eight years ago” can be no earlier than 1907. This suggests that he had more than one failure, so that his “last failure” is not the same case as ‘The Clue of the Chocolate Box’.
- > [Inspector Japp] turned to the other man. “You’ve heard me speak of Mr. Poirot? It was in **1904** he and I worked together—the Abercrombie forgery case—you remember, he was run down in Brussels. Ah, those were great days, moosier. Then, do you remember ‘Baron’ Altara? There was a pretty rogue for you! He eluded the clutches of half the police in Europe. But we nailed him in Antwerp—thanks to Mr. Poirot here.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1920). [*The Mysterious Affair at Styles*, chapter 7](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Affair_at_Styles/Chapter_7). London: Bodley Head.</sub>
- In *Three Act Tragedy*, Poirot says that he was “due to retire” from the Belgian police on the eve of the First World War:

  > “See you, as a boy I was poor. There were many of us. We had to get on in the world. I entered the Police Force. I worked hard. Slowly I rose in that Force. I began to make a name for myself. I made a name for myself. I began to acquire an international reputation. At last, I was due to retire. There came the War. I was injured. I came, a sad and weary refugee, to England.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1934). *Three Act Tragedy*, chapter 6. London: Collins.</sub>
- *The Mysterious Affair at Styles* is not precisely dated, but it is set during the First World War. Captain Arthur Hastings has been “invalided home from the Front”, Mary Cavendish is a [Land Girl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_Land_Army_(World_War_I)), Cynthia Murdoch is a  pharmacist in the [Voluntary Aid Detachment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voluntary_Aid_Detachment), Mrs Inglethorp says, “We are quite a war household; nothing is wasted here”, and there are Belgian refugees in the village. Some time around 1916 seems to be indicated, and this date is confirmed by Hastings in *Curtain*:

  > Ah! If I could go back—live life all over again. If this could have been that day in **1916** when I first travelled to Styles…
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1975). *Curtain: Poirot’s Last Case*, chapter 1. London: Collins.</sub>
- *Curtain* is set during or after the Second World War, according to Hastings:

  > How long ago was it that I had taken this self-same journey? Had felt (ridiculously) that the best of life was over for me! Wounded in that war that for me would always be *the* war—the war that was wiped out now by a **second and a more desperate war**.
  >
  > <sub>*Curtain*, chapter 1.</sub>

  A remark from Poirot suggests that the war is ongoing or only recently concluded, otherwise “the last war” would be the Second World War, not the First:

  > “Like your Mr Asquith **in the last war**.”
  >
  > <sub>*Curtain*, chapter 8.</sub>

  Hastings meets “an old woman with rheumy eyes and an unpleasantly ghoulish manner” who describes the passage of time since the earlier novel:

  > “**Twenty years ago and over**. When the old lady died up at the Court. That was the first murder we had to Styles. Won’t be the last, I say. Old Mrs Inglethorp, her husband done her in, so we all said. Sure of it, we was.”
  >
  > <sub>*Curtain*, chapter 15.</sub>

  This would seem to place *Curtain* in the mid-1940s: indeed, by 1946, it would already be thirty years since Mrs Inglethorp’s murder.
- *Hallowe’en Party* is set after the [suspension of capital punishment for murder in 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_(Abolition_of_Death_Penalty)_Act_1965):

  > Faint memories flashed across his mind. Rather a celebrated case, more celebrated actually than it had showed any signs of being, a case that had seemed cut and dried. Of course! It came to him that his nephew Robert had been connected with it, had been Junior Counsel. A psychopathic killer, it had seemed, a man who had hardly bothered to try and defend himself, a man whom you might have thought really wanted to be hanged (because it had meant hanging at that time). No fifteen years, or indefinite number of years in prison. No. You paid the full penalty and **more’s the pity they’ve given it up**, so Mr Fullerton thought in his dry mind.
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1969). *Hallowe’en Party*, chapter 12. London: Collins.</sub>

  (This paragraph references the events of *Mrs McGinty’s Dead*, 1952.)
- *Elephants Can Remember* is set in the early 1970s:

  > “A speech!” Mrs. Oliver sounded horrified. “No, of course not. You know I never make speeches.”
  >
  > “Well, I thought they always did at these here literary luncheons. That’s what you’re going to, isn’t it? Famous writers of **nineteen seventy-three**—or wherever year it is we’ve got to now.”
  >
  > <sub>Agatha Christie (1972). *Elephants Can Remember*, chapter 1. London: Collins.</sub>

  > “What I want," said Mrs. Oliver with firmness and the determination of a spoiled child, "is my **nineteen seventy** address book. And I think **nineteen sixty-nine** as well. Please look for it as quick as you can, will you?”
  >
  > <sub>*Elephants Can Remember*, chapter 3.</sub>

#### Consistency

Since *Curtain* is ‘Poirot’s Last Case’ and so would have to follow *Hallowe’en Party* and *Elephants Can Remember* in any coherent biography, the only way to make the chronology consistent would be to imagine that the characters are mistaken or lying or joking in some or all of these works. But I think that’s a sign that such an exercise would be [futile](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FanWank).

Christie was well aware of this. She satirizes the difficulty of having such a long-running series detective in *Mrs McGinty’s Dead*, where crime novelist Ariadne Oliver and playwright Robin Upwood are collaborating on a play in which Oliver’s Finnish detective, Sven Hjerson, is to be the hero:

> Robin continued blithely: “What I feel is, here’s that wonderful young man, parachuted down—”
>
> Mrs Oliver interrupted: “He’s sixty.”
>
> “Oh no!”
>
> “He is.”
>
> “I don’t see him like that. Thirty-five—not a day older.”
>
> “But I’ve been writing books about him for thirty years, and he was at least thirty-five in the first one.”
>
> “But, darling, if he’s sixty, you can’t have the tension between him and the girl—what’s her name? Ingrid. I mean, it would make him just a nasty old man!”
>
> “It certainly would.”
>
> <sub>Agatha Christie (1952). *Mrs McGinty’s Dead*, chapter 12. London: Collins.</sub>

However, nothing in Christie’s oeuvre suggests that she was all that bothered by series consistency. While they may share characters, each novel and story stands on its own. There are occasional references to other stories but these are never important to the plot. It’s not just Poirot’s age that varies: for example, Hastings is about to marry Dulcie Duveen at the conclusion of *The Murder on the Links* (1923) but in *Peril at End House* (1932) he calls his wife ‘Bella’, the name of Dulcie’s twin sister in the earlier novel.

Answer (score -3):

Hercules Poirot was born in Belgium, between 1875 and 1880 … or before. He entered the Belgian police when 18 years old, between 1893 and 1898. He retired from the Belgian police with 22 years of service, between 1915 and 1918. He arrived in England between 1916 and 1918, because the First World War was ending.

His first case was The Mystery of Styles in 1920, when he was between 40 and 45 years old. Here there is a small discrepancy, because if he arrived in England at the end of the war, his first case should have been in 1916/1918 and not in 1920, but let's continue. He died in Curtain in May 1975, the New York Times published his death. So when he died he should be between 95 and 100 years old, or more.

But there is another version: the letter addressed to Hastings, where Poirot explains how he solved the Curtain case, is dated October 1949. With this version, he should be between 69 and 74 years old when he died.

Conclusion: between 69 and 100 . . . or more. There is no exact way to know how old Poirot was at death.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What is your source for this information? I'm not saying any of it is wrong, but the answer would be more useful if we can see where you got the info.

Comment: 60 years of reading all the Agatha books several times, watching all the movies several times and reading notes about the subject. I am AC collector.

Comment: That's *how* you obtained the information, not *where*.

Comment: Yes, you are right ! - The info is in the books,,,

Comment: Could you quote the passages you are relying on? For example, when you write, "The letter [in *Curtain*] is dated October 1949", which edition are you using? I checked my copy and the letter is undated.

Comment: In movie Curtain, Season 13, Ep 5,  with David Suched, on minute 1:06:35 , when Poirot stars writting the letter, you can see "Oct 1949" , up on the left., . . . IF YOU DO NOT BELIEVE ME, PLEASE SEE THAT MOVIE ! - Best regards.

Comment: You mean the ITV series starring David Suchet, yes? But this moves all the stories to a common time period (mostly 1930s), regardless of when Christie originally set them. There is no difficulty with Poirot's age in the ITV series. The difficulty appears in the books only.

Comment: Yes, this is why I say that there are some discrepancies and it is impossible to be sure about the age, because movies, books and opinions do not concide. New York Times published Poirot death in 1975.

Comment: In Suched movie "Third girl", they talk about "The Beatles", since Beatles performed in the sixties, how can Poirot be death in 1949 but talk abot Beatles ? - More discrepancies ? - Please, tell me, I want to understand !